# Connection to ovh cloud in node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, cloud, object-storage, ovh

I want to connect to ovh cloud with axios.

```
const username = 'user-123456';
    const accessKey = '1242121414421';
    const secretKey = '2414124141';
    const containerName = 'storage';
    const endpoint = 'https://s3.de.io.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_' + accessKey + '/' + containerName;
await axios
        .post('https://auth.cloud.ovh.net/v3/auth/tokens', {
            auth: {
                identity: {
                    methods: ['password'],
                    password: {
                        user: {
                            name: username,
                            domain: { id: 'default' },
                            password: secretKey,
                        },
                    },
                },
                scope: {
                    project: { id: containerName },
                    domain: { id: 'default' },
                },
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const token = response.data.token.id;

            // List containers
            axios
                .get(`https://${containerName}.s3.de.io.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_${accessKey}`, {
                    headers: {
                        'X-Auth-Token': token,
                    },
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error listing containers:', error.message);
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error authenticating:', error);
            console.log('Error details:', error.response.data);
        });
```

I am getting error like this: Error details: Expecting to find system, project, domain, OS-TRUST:trust or unscoped in scope. The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. The client is assumed to be in error.

I can't figured out what's wrong